# Add Headers to Response with Service Worker

Tags: javascript, promise, service-worker

I'm trying to add extra headers to a specific fetch response. I've installed a service worker , intercepted the request but I'm getting the error below when I try to handle it (copy and add extra headers). Any idea how to fix it?

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'respondWith' on 'FetchEvent': The event handler is already finished.`

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log("sw request ", event.request);
  if (!event.request.url.startsWith("file://")){
      try{
        event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
     return;
   }

 fetch(event.request).then(response => {
  const newHeaders = new Headers(response.headers);
  newHeaders.append('Cache-Control', 'max-age=300');

  const responseExtra = new Response(response.body, {
    status: response.status,
    statusText: response.statusText,
    headers: newHeaders
  });
 event.respondWith(responseExtra);

});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

respondWidth() is called before your new `Response` is in scope.  This is due to how Promises like fetch() work.  Try something like :

```
const newResponse = fetch(event.request).then(response => {
  const newHeaders = new Headers(response.headers);
  newHeaders.append('Cache-Control', 'max-age=300');

  return new Response(response.body, {
    status: response.status,
    statusText: response.statusText,
    headers: newHeaders
  });
});

event.respondWith(newResponse);
```